# Downscaling data while keeping host tag separate

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I'm trying to downscale a bit of old data in influxdb. Basically, my measurements contain values from several different hosts, and I need to keep them separate. So, I'm trying to aggregate data to 5m intervals, but keep the host values separate.

I tried as follows, but that fails with a syntax error "mixing multiple selector functions with tags or fields is not supported":

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY cq_5m_net ON telegraf 
 BEGIN SELECT 
 max(bytes_recv) AS bytes_recv, max(bytes_sent) AS bytes_sent, 
 max(drop_in) AS drop_in, max(drop_out) AS drop_out, 
 max(err_in) AS err_in, max(err_out) AS err_out, 
 host INTO telegraf.rp_5m.net 
FROM telegraf.autogen.net GROUP BY time(5m), * 
END
```

Can this be accomplished some other way?

Also, raw dataset looks like this (a bit simplified):

```
time           host       bytes_recv   bytes_sent    drop_in drop_out
----           ----       ----------   ----------    ------- --------
14805418900000 web2.x.net 6358608058 5036008977 148414  0
14805419000000 web3.x.net 6358600106 5036501326 148414  0
14805419100000 web2.x.net 6358604711 5036770259 148414  0
14805419200000 web3.x.net 6358602310 5038123405 148414  0
14805419300000 web2.x.net 6358600274 5039360985 148414  0
14805419400000 web2.x.net 6358618730 5039651324 148414  0
14805419500000 web2.x.net 6358616379 5030898027 148414  0
14805419600000 web3.x.net 6358612454 5031543210 148414  0
14805419700000 web3.x.net 6358611562 5032444497 148414  0
14805419800000 web3.x.net 6358610357 5032699567 148414  0
```

Answer (score 1):

**[That](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/7802)** explains what kind of issue you have.

The downright generic answer to your question ("*Can this be accomplished some other way?*") is - yes, the other-way's name is **[Kapacitor](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.5/)**.

For more detailed answer regarding the query, you provide more details first, please - how your measurement looks like?

But the main question here: why do you need that permanent downsampling at all?

Data storage is cheap (as data records seems to be pretty lean), time interval based aggregations on the fly are cheap and fast for properly shaped data - you just can do it any time you need it in a blink of an eye.

Can you justify why do you roll this way?

Comment: I added dataset sample. In this case, I just want to keep a long-term history of internet traffic to my servers. So I can check evolution through time.
And yes, I'm a bit limited on disk space.

Comment: Then, if you insist, the good way would be to keep retention period relatively short for main measurement (just what you need for current monitoring/alerting needs), then spin a Kapacitor job that would do the aggregation in batches on regular basis, over a backdated data, and write the aggregated data into archive measurement. Simple & lean solution.